# M-file's initial parameters in Simulink

Tags: simulink

http://www.edaboard.com/attachments/79848d1347097103-255.png
Dear all,
I used m-file on Simulink by Matlab Function as shown in attached pic, In m-fie I write a code with parameters that need to have initialize value , for example the code is:

```
[HTML]
function out=control(in)
rin=in(1);
for j=1:1:6
h(j)=exp(-norm(x-ci(:,j))^2/(2*bi(j)*bi(j)));
end
x(1)=h;
x(2)=rin;
```

it is needed to set initial value fr x as [0 , 0], but how is possible in Simulink?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
x = zeros(1,2,'double'); % after function out=control(in)
```

Appropriately change data type if it throws error.